# Comparing PCAP Datasets

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I'm having some issues coming up with the best approach to compare two PCAP files.

So I have two PCAPs, the first is a known bad application. The second is an unknown application. What I would like to do is compare these using some form of Machine Learning (through python) technique that would tell me how similar they are. Maybe a percentage of similarity. Maybe something that says, PCAP_2 is 70% similar to PCAP_1. Or a plot that I can see where PCAP_2 lays ontop of PCAP_1 as well as any outliers.

I have been able to use a tool that extracts around 70 features from the PCAPs and generate a CSV file. For the first PCAP (evil pcap), it comes out to be a CSV with 70 columns (the features) and around 200K rows (the flows found in the PCAP). The second PCAP has around 25K rows.

So far, I have injested the CSVs into a Pandas DataFrame, massaged the data some, normalized it, and scaled it with StandardScaler. Everything seems to be working fine. My first thought was to just plot them, so I ran the evil PCAP through T-SNE and PCA (separately), to come up with a 2D array to plot. Using T-SNE comes up with just a big circular blob, while PCA seems to do better, but is just plot that make lines. I feel that I'm doing something wrong.

Is there a better way of attacking this? Maybe throwing a label to PCAP_1 calling it Evil, and running it through a supervisored model?  Which one would be best for this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow's format is a good fit for *narrow*, *specific* questions, particularly about tactical (vs strategic) programming issues; open-ended questions are explicitly outside our focus. There are other sites in the Stack Exchange network with a more specific focus on data science, and which may have less stringent topicality rules. In particular, see [When is Cross Validated more appropriate than Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199677/when-to-post-on-cross-validated-over-stack-overflow) for guidelines on deciding between SO and our sister site [stats.se].

Comment: [Which stack exchange website for machine learning and computational algorithms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms) is another [meta.se] question with pertinent guidance.